# php daily counter mutiple access bug

Tags: php, web, parallel-processing

I'm writing , just to experiment , a web page daily hit counter using PHP.

Multiple access from the same browser during the same day should be counted as 1,
in order to do that I'm using cookies.

The problem is that , before the browser gets the cookie , the script can be executed in parallel multiple times without any thread finding the cookie , therefore the counter does not work as expected.

So how can I avoid the script is executed in parallel to serve requests coming from the same browser ?

thanks.

Here's the example:
note that to make debugging easier the day is now 1 minute long :D,
the counter is the second value from the left.
http://ralfralf.atwebpages.com/index2.php

here's the code:
(can someone help me making it look readeable?) :D

```
<?php

$visitsfile = file("visits.txt");

if( ! isset($_COOKIE["visitor"] ) )
  {
    $rest = time() % 60;
    $rest1 = 60 - $rest;
    setcookie("visitor" , "visitor" , time() + $rest1 );

    $bolval = 0;

    if( sizeof($visitsfile) > 0)
      {
        $i = sizeof($visitsfile) - 2;

        $val = floor( ( intval( substr( $visitsfile[$i] , 0 , - 1) ) / 60 ) ) - floor( ( time() / 60 ) ) ;

        if(  $val == 0 )
          {
            $visitsfile[$i+1] = intval( substr( $visitsfile[$i + 1] , 0 , - 1) ) + 1 . "\n";
            $bolval = 1;
          }
      }       

    if( sizeof($visitsfile) == 0 || !$bolval)
      {
        if(sizeof($visitsfile) == 0)
          {
            $i = 0;
          }
        else
          {
            $i = sizeof($visitsfile);
          }

        $visitsfile[$i] = time() . "\n";
        $visitsfile[$i+1] = "1\n";
      }

    $fp = fopen("visits.txt", "w");

    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX))
      {
        $i = 0;
        while($i < sizeof($visitsfile))
          {
            fwrite($fp, $visitsfile[$i] );
            $i++;
          }
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
      }
    fclose($fp);
  }

$n = sizeof($visitsfile);

if(! isset($_COOKIE["visitor"]))
  {
    echo intval( substr( $visitsfile[$n - 2] , 0 , - 1) ) . " " . (intval( substr( $visitsfile[$n - 1] , 0 , - 1) ) - 1 ) ;
  }
else
  {
    echo intval( substr( $visitsfile[$n - 2] , 0 , - 1) ) . " " . intval( substr( $visitsfile[$n - 1] , 0 , - 1) ) ;
  }


?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is solvable without causing other problems. But you should post your code if you want people to help you fix it.

Comment: For most web sites, perfect accuracy of hit counters is not critical. So they don't worry about corner cases like this, just as they don't worry about people who clear their caches. Is your page likely to be accessed in parallel frequently?

Comment: Use the `{}` tool to mark code

Comment: thanks for editing :D , well really it is not , it's just an example just to experiment with myself, so there's no way to tell PHP engine not to accept parallel requests coming from the same browser ?

Comment: The whole reason you're using the cookie is to detect when requests come from the same browser, isn't it? Until the cookie is set, there's no way for the server to tell that two connections are from the same browser. If there were, you wouldn't need the cookie.

Comment: Yes , I'm just realising that :) , thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW, there seem to be problems in your code. You assign `$resto` and `$resto1`, but use `$rest` and `rest1`.

Comment: well the code I'm running is correct, I just was tryng to translate some variables name in english wich is not my native language.I'm gonna edit that

Comment: What you could do is keep track of IPs that have connected without cookies. If you see the same IP without a cookie, treat it as a repeat. An IP doesn't uniquely define a browser (because of proxies and NAT), but it's unlikely that two browsers behind the same IP will hit so closely together.

Comment: Yeah using IPs is a possibility , thanks.